# React JS How to Add and Remove item in a State Array from one function

Tags: reactjs, arrays

Using React JS Class Component.

In a single function I am trying to...
Add a value (int) to an array if it doesnt exist in the array
and vice versa..
Remove a value (int) from an array if it does exist in the array.

Note, initially the array will be empty []

My final C# service is expecting a string[] so I assume array should be...
["1, "2", "3"] and not [1,2,3] although the selected value will be an int.

```
this.state = {            
            selectedMembers: [],

}
```

I've tried various methods using **push, includes, indexOf** but get errors like '..is not a function'

Answer (score 0):

You might be running into the problem of trying to mutate React state directly. By default, React state is read-only and so applying functions like .push() will have no affect on an array you stored in state (like your array selectedMemebers). Instead, a solution is to create a copy of the state array, mutate it as desired, and then update your state to the mutated copy. Here is a function you can place within your class component to accomplish your request:

```
const myFunction = (value) => {
        let selectedMembersCopy = [...this.state.selectedMembers]; \\ creating copy
        let index = selectedMembersCopy.indexOf(val);
        
        if(index < -1){
            selectedMembersCopy.push(value);
        }
        else {
            selectedMembersCopy.splice(index, 1);
        }
        this.setState({
            selectedMembers: selectedMembersCopy
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Aiden for your reply,  I'm getting 'a ref error: val is not defined'